# Creating fake software box images

Tags: macos, images

Is there a program for OS X that can be used to create "fake" software box images?

I'm basically looking for something that will let me create this, but without Photoshop.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/11111/best-cheap-or-free-image-editing-application-for-mac

Comment: I think this is niche enough to warrant a separate question.  I don't feel it's as trivial as Daisetsu claims, esp. w/ Photoshop weighing $1000+ (waiting for paint.net plug).  If someone just wants to sell software that doesn't actually ship but thinks a tangible box looks professional, they need this.  I've used a free one before and it's a lot easier than PS/Fireworks/gimp etc.  See also http://superuser.com/questions/105990/whats-up-with-software-box-shots/105992#105992.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Couple all that with it being a Mac app: it won't be easy to find.

Comment: doh, spoke too soon: http://www.boxshot3d.com/screenshots/mac-os-x/

Comment: If you want to drop that into an answer it'll likely be the best one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Box Shot 3D](http://www.boxshot3d.com/) has a Windows and Max version.  It renders high quality images, and does shadows, reflections, transparency, etc.  You can even render [books, business cards, and soda cans](http://www.boxshot3d.com/gallery/).  Ironically, you can only order online so they likely don't ship you a box, but hey that's what this is all about, right?  **USD 60** at time of writing.

I just tried out the demo for fun and this is about as easy as it gets.  Even if I was printing/shipping a product, I'd buy this just to mock up the box and spin it around on all axes to get an idea of how it will look on the shelf.

The real version does not have the watermarks (black horizontal lines).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create such Box-Shots with [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) (respectively the [MacOS version of it](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/)). On the other hand it might also be possible using [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) for the rendering, and any paint program for the texture of the box.